# d3.select('rect id').attr('y') returns Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

Tags: d3.js

After having created several rectangles each with a different `id`, I would like to get their `x` attribute. From several questions on SO, I found that I should do this:

```
d3.select('rect name1').attr('x')`
```

But it returns:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null`,

Even though `d3.select('rect name1')` doesn't give a error and returns `st {_groups: Array(1), _parents: Array(1)}`

```
var dataRectangle = [];
for (var i=0; i < 10 ; i++) {
 dataRectangle.push(i);
}    
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', 1024)
    .attr('height', 500);
var baseCircle = svg.selectAll('rect');
baseCircle = baseCircle.data(dataRectangle).enter().append('g');
baseCircle.append('rect')
        .attr('width', 10)
        .attr('height', 10)
        .attr('x', 20)
        .attr('y', 20)
        .attr('fill', "none")
        .attr("stroke-width", 4)
        .style('stroke', "green")
        .attr("id", function(d, i) { return 'name'+i; });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you have to use `#` for IDs:

```
d3.select('rect #name1').attr('x')
```

But this is not the only problem. Besides that, there is a wrong space here:

```
d3.select('rect #name1').attr('x')
//space here---^
```

Because of that, you're selecting all the elements with that given ID that are **children** of the `<rect>`. Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors

Obviously, there is none. You said that...

> d3.select('rect name1') doesn't give a error and returns st {_groups: Array(1), _parents: Array(1)}

... but, if you look at that selection, you'll see that it is an **empty** selection. Let's prove it:

```js
var dataRectangle = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  dataRectangle.push(i);
}
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', 300)
  .attr('height', 200);
var baseCircle = svg.selectAll('rect');
baseCircle = baseCircle.data(dataRectangle).enter().append('g');
baseCircle.append('rect')
  .attr('width', 10)
  .attr('height', 10)
  .attr('x', 20)
  .attr('y', 20)
  .attr('fill', "none")
  .attr("stroke-width", 4)
  .style('stroke', "green")
  .attr("id", function(d, i) {
    return 'name' + i;
  });

console.log("The size of the selection is: " + d3.select('rect name1').size())
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

And that explains why you cannot `read property 'getAttribute' of null`.

**Solution**

It should be:

```
d3.select('rect#name1').attr('x')
```

Or, since IDs are **unique**, simply:

```
d3.select('#name1').attr('x')
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var dataRectangle = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  dataRectangle.push(i);
}
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', 300)
  .attr('height', 200);
var baseCircle = svg.selectAll('rect');
baseCircle = baseCircle.data(dataRectangle).enter().append('g');
baseCircle.append('rect')
  .attr('width', 10)
  .attr('height', 10)
  .attr('x', 20)
  .attr('y', 20)
  .attr('fill', "none")
  .attr("stroke-width", 4)
  .style('stroke', "green")
  .attr("id", function(d, i) {
    return 'name' + i;
  });

console.log(d3.select('rect#name1').attr("x"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This error also shows up if you don't have a  tag in your html file. for example. you are calling `d3.select("svg")` but there is no svg element defined in the html file.